# Storing multiple values in one column vs. Multiple columns for multiple values

Tags: sql, row, storage

With regards to Performance & 'The proper way of doing things' and trying to figure out which way is better to store configuration data in a SQL database. Assume you have website configuration data for setting a minimum and maximum age that a person must be to access the site.

```
CREATE TABLE SiteConfig
(
  featureName varchar(100),
  value varchar(100),
)
```

Which is better:

- To store it all in a single row and process it in PHP with explode();.

  featureName: "ageRequirement"

  value: "13|60"
- To store it in separate rows for each feature and just SELECT the feature you need when needed.

  featureName: "minAge"

  value: "13"

  featureName: "maxAge"

  value: "60"

**Due to the amount of features of the website, this is a difference of having 60 ROWS of data vs. about 25.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store it has two separate features.

You may want to access the feature in the database, rather than in the application code.

There is no reason to parse a comma delimited string to get two features.

Admittedly, in the case of just two numbers separated by a comma, not much can go wrong.  This is, however, a slippery slope and you might soon find yourself trying to stuff multiple fields into a single string, and then devoting a lot of resources to parsing the string.

Answer (score 0):

If those are values that you never will use by themselves in the database, either would work.

If you suspect that you would ever want to use the value in the database, you would not want them in the same value. That would make querying the data complicated and inefficient.

Comment: That was my thought too. The example I gave is a simple one but there are many other features that would have 2-5 different variables in it if I went that route. I was just worried about having to make too many SELECT statements to obtain the data.

Comment: @Vidarious: You might want to have separate columns for the different settings instead of rows, that makes it easier to fetch them. Also, you can use different data types for different values. For example, an `int` seems to be a better fit for the minimum and maximum age values.